# I want to test a controller without using @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have the following test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ChoreControllerTest
{
    @Autowired 
    private ChoreController controller;

    @Test
    public void throwOnMissingChore()
    {
        assertThrows(ChoreNotFoundException.class, () -> this.controller.getChore(0L));
    }
}
```

It takes about 5 seconds for Spring Boot to start up so the test can run. I want to reduce this time, but if I just remove the `@SpringBootTest` annotaton, I just get a NPE.

Is there a way to make this controller test more lightweight, or am I stuck with the startup time? I'm especially worried about what will happen to my test times if I ever want to test more than one controller....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@SpringBootTest` annotations create a Spring Context for you therefore it takes a while to start up. This annotation is mostly used for integration tests where a Spring context is required. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests) are a few tips for optimizing integration tests.
If you remove the annotation the ChoreController cannot be autowired (no context available) which results in a NullpointerException.
Depending on your needs you can just use a Mocking library like Mockito to inject mocks e.g. services that your controller class needs and run the test without the `@SpringBootTest`.

You might want to take a look at this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension) for setting up those mocks properly.